# How to optimize php syntax

Tags: php, if-statement

PHP call below is working fine, but maybe there is another, cleaner way to display the same?

```
<?php if ($this['modules']->count('top-a')) : ?>
       <?php if ($this['config']->get('warp_onlyhome')) : ?>
          <?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); if ($catid == 0) : ?>
    <section id="top-a" class="grid-block"><?php echo $this['modules']->render('top-a', array('layout'=>$this['config']->get('top-a'))); ?></section>
          <?php endif ?>
          <?php else: ?>
    <section id="top-a" class="grid-block"><?php echo $this['modules']->render('top-a', array('layout'=>$this['config']->get('top-a'))); ?></section>
        <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: read a book or a tutorial before you ask questions like this here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `else:`.

```
<?php if ($this['config']->get('warp_onlyhome')) : ?>
   <?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); if ($catid == 0) : ?>

my content goes here

   <?php endif: ?>
   <?php else: ?>

my content 2

<?php endif; ?>
```

Less insane formatting:

```
if ($this['config']->get('warp_onlyhome')) {
   $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); 
   if ($catid == 0) {
      echo "my content goes here";
   }
} else {

  echo "my content 2";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the example how to use if else embedding.

```
<? if ($condition): ?>
  <p>Content</p>
<? elseif ($other_condition): ?>
  <p>Other Content</p>
<? else: ?>
  <p>Default Content</p>
<? endif; ?>
```

See [more example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) and [alternative](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).